# OpenTok: Is it possible to publish a stream from a broadcasted TV channel?

Tags: opentok

We have a TV channel, and we are thinking of creating an android App to display our channel, live. I am looking for the right solutions for that.

I just got in touch with OpenTok, and it seems to be mostly about streaming phone's camera or webcam.

So before going deep with my team, I would like to know if OpenTok can also publish streamed live video channel, and continuously, or at least as long as, or as soon as, there is an active subscription on the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What format is your TV channel in? If you can play it in a video tag, you could use Chrome/Chromium via [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to play the video, and use [captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream) to pass the stream into the OpenTok JS SDK. You could of course also observe when users are added or removed from the session to turn on/ turn off this publisher.

It might also be better to look at [HLS streaming](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/broadcast/), which OpenTok also supports. It *might* be best to skip the OpenTok step and go straight to a HLS stream.